# Github actions Unity toy example

Tags: unity-game-engine, github-actions

I try to setup a toy Unity project to play around with github actions. I'm following a [simple tutorial](https://isaacbroyles.com/gamedev/2020/07/04/unity-github-actions.html). I can run a successful `.github/workflows/activation.yml` action as described in the above tutorial. However, already the next step is failing. Given my Unity activation I'm trying to run the following simple test:

```
name: Test

on:
  pull_request: {}
  push: { branches: [master] }

env:
  UNITY_LICENSE: ${{ secrets.UNITY_LICENSE }}

jobs:
  build:
    name: Test project
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      # Checkout
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          lfs: true
    
      # Cache
      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: Library
          key: Library

      # Test
      - name: Run tests
        uses: game-ci/unity-test-runner@v2
        with:
          unityVersion: 2020.3.15f2
```

The test fails, and the log is very lenghty, so I'm not sure what the exact problem is. Here is the log:

```
Run game-ci/unity-test-runner@v2
  with:
    unityVersion: 2020.3.15f2
    testMode: all
    coverageOptions: generateAdditionalMetrics;generateHtmlReport;generateBadgeReport
    artifactsPath: artifacts
    useHostNetwork: false
    checkName: Test Results
  env:
    UNITY_LICENSE: ***
/usr/bin/docker run --workdir /github/workspace --rm --env UNITY_LICENSE --env UNITY_LICENSE_FILE --env UNITY_EMAIL --env UNITY_PASSWORD --env UNITY_SERIAL --env UNITY_VERSION=2020.3.15f2 --env PROJECT_PATH=. --env CUSTOM_PARAMETERS= --env TEST_PLATFORMS=playmode;editmode;COMBINE_RESULTS --env COVERAGE_OPTIONS=generateAdditionalMetrics;generateHtmlReport;generateBadgeReport --env COVERAGE_RESULTS_PATH=CodeCoverage --env ARTIFACTS_PATH=artifacts --env GITHUB_REF --env GITHUB_SHA --env GITHUB_REPOSITORY --env GITHUB_ACTOR --env GITHUB_WORKFLOW --env GITHUB_HEAD_REF --env GITHUB_BASE_REF --env GITHUB_EVENT_NAME --env GITHUB_WORKSPACE=/github/workspace --env GITHUB_ACTION --env GITHUB_EVENT_PATH --env RUNNER_OS --env RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE --env RUNNER_TEMP --env RUNNER_WORKSPACE --env GIT_PRIVATE_TOKEN= --env CHOWN_FILES_TO= --volume /home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home:/root:z --volume /home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow:/github/workflow:z --volume /home/runner/work/CiCdProject/CiCdProject:/github/workspace:z --volume /home/runner/work/_actions/game-ci/unity-test-runner/v2/dist/steps:/steps:z --volume /home/runner/work/_actions/game-ci/unity-test-runner/v2/dist/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh:z --env USE_EXIT_CODE=true unityci/editor:ubuntu-2020.3.15f2-linux-il2cpp-1 /bin/bash -c /entrypoint.sh
Unable to find image 'unityci/editor:ubuntu-2020.3.15f2-linux-il2cpp-1' locally
ubuntu-2020.3.15f2-linux-il2cpp-1: Pulling from unityci/editor
08a6abff8943: Pulling fs layer
17bc3eeef474: Pulling fs layer
7525af58113d: Pulling fs layer
643424925c07: Pulling fs layer
a64283161285: Pulling fs layer
6f8bb29b92de: Pulling fs layer
f93bd952912f: Pulling fs layer
73fbdbda7cd3: Pulling fs layer
d9a4cec5ee9b: Pulling fs layer
4657a6a72083: Pulling fs layer
4f4fb700ef54: Pulling fs layer
f397d9313f62: Pulling fs layer
643424925c07: Waiting
a64283161285: Waiting
6f8bb29b92de: Waiting
f93bd952912f: Waiting
73fbdbda7cd3: Waiting
d9a4cec5ee9b: Waiting
4657a6a72083: Waiting
4f4fb700ef54: Waiting
f397d9313f62: Waiting
17bc3eeef474: Verifying Checksum
17bc3eeef474: Download complete
08a6abff8943: Verifying Checksum
08a6abff8943: Download complete
a64283161285: Verifying Checksum
a64283161285: Download complete
643424925c07: Verifying Checksum
643424925c07: Download complete
6f8bb29b92de: Verifying Checksum
6f8bb29b92de: Download complete
f93bd952912f: Verifying Checksum
f93bd952912f: Download complete
d9a4cec5ee9b: Verifying Checksum
d9a4cec5ee9b: Download complete
4657a6a72083: Verifying Checksum
4657a6a72083: Download complete
4f4fb700ef54: Verifying Checksum
4f4fb700ef54: Download complete
7525af58113d: Verifying Checksum
7525af58113d: Download complete
f397d9313f62: Verifying Checksum
f397d9313f62: Download complete
08a6abff8943: Pull complete
17bc3eeef474: Pull complete
7525af58113d: Pull complete
643424925c07: Pull complete
a64283161285: Pull complete
6f8bb29b92de: Pull complete
f93bd952912f: Pull complete
73fbdbda7cd3: Verifying Checksum
73fbdbda7cd3: Download complete
73fbdbda7cd3: Pull complete
d9a4cec5ee9b: Pull complete
4657a6a72083: Pull complete
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete
f397d9313f62: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:1046f6280f5798028870d5e5e0c881d4d66a950f1a25f0dbbb3b75fe865b6e48
Status: Downloaded newer image for unityci/editor:ubuntu-2020.3.15f2-linux-il2cpp-1
Changing to "/github/workspace/_activate-license" directory.
/github/workspace/_activate-license /github/workspace
Requesting activation (personal license)
Activation complete.
/github/workspace
/steps/set_gitcredential.sh: line 1: ﻿#!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
GIT_PRIVATE_TOKEN unset skipping
---------- git config --list -------------
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
---------- git config --list --show-origin -------------
file:/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
file:/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
file:/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.required=true
file:/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
Using project path "/github/workspace/.".
Using artifacts path "artifacts" to save test results.
Using coverage results path "CodeCoverage" to save test coverage results.
Using custom parameters .
Using Unity version "2020.3.15f2" to test.

###########################
#    Artifacts folder     #
###########################

Creating "/github/workspace/artifacts" if it does not exist.

###########################
#    Project directory    #
###########################

total 40K
drwxr-xr-x 9 1001  121 4.0K Nov  4 11:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Nov  4 11:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x 9 1001  121 4.0K Nov  4 11:51 .git
drwxr-xr-x 3 1001  121 4.0K Nov  4 11:51 .github
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001  121 1.4K Nov  4 11:51 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x 6 1001  121 4.0K Nov  4 11:51 Assets
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001  121 4.0K Nov  4 11:51 Packages
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001  121 4.0K Nov  4 11:51 ProjectSettings
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov  4 11:53 _activate-license
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov  4 11:53 artifacts

###########################
#   Testing in playmode  #
###########################

[Licensing::Module] Channel doesn't exist: "LicenseClient-root"
[Licensing::Module] Successfully launched the LicensingClient (PId: 90)
[SignatureVerifier] Application signature verification not supported on this platform.
[Licensing::Module] Successfully connected to LicensingClient on channel: "LicenseClient-root" (connect: 0.95s, validation: 0.06s, handshake: 0.00s)
[Licensing::Module] Connected to LicensingClient (PId: 90, launch time: 0.00, total connection time: 1.01s)
Entitlement-based licensing initiated
[LicensingClient] Licenses updated successfully
Desktop is 640 x 480 @ 60 Hz

LICENSE SYSTEM [2022114 11:53:33] Next license update check is after 2022-11-04T15:56:03


LICENSE SYSTEM [2022114 11:53:33] Current license is already valid and activated. Skipping license activation process (Provided username/password will be ignored).
[Licensing::Module] Serial number assigned to: "F4-YA49-V8UH-G27B-6NHM-XXXX"
[Package Manager] Server::Start -- Port 51195 was selected

 COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS:
/opt/unity/Editor/Unity
-batchmode
-batchmode
-logFile
/github/workspace/artifacts/playmode.log
-projectPath
/github/workspace/.
-coverageResultsPath
/github/workspace/CodeCoverage
-runTests
-testPlatform
playmode
-testResults
/github/workspace/artifacts/playmode-results.xml
-enableCodeCoverage
-debugCodeOptimization
-coverageOptions
generateAdditionalMetrics;generateHtmlReport;generateBadgeReport
Successfully changed project path to: /github/workspace/.
/github/workspace
Using Asset Import Pipeline V2.
Rebuilding Library because the asset database could not be found!

[Package Manager] Done resolving packages in 35.12s seconds
[Package Manager] Done checking package constraints in 0.00s seconds
[Package Manager] 
Registered 45 packages:
  Packages from [https://packages.unity.com]:
    com.unity.automated-testing@0.8.1-preview.2 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.automated-testing@0.8.1-preview.2)
    com.unity.collab-proxy@1.15.7 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.15.7)
    com.unity.ide.rider@2.0.7 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.rider@2.0.7)
    com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.12 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.12)
    com.unity.ide.vscode@1.2.4 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.vscode@1.2.4)
    com.unity.test-framework@1.1.33 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.test-framework@1.1.33)
    com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0.6 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0.6)
    com.unity.timeline@1.4.8 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.timeline@1.4.8)
    com.unity.ext.nunit@1.0.6 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ext.nunit@1.0.6)
    com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0.0 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0.0)
    com.unity.services.core@1.0.1 (location: 
[... some more similar lines ...]
    com.unity.modules.xr@1.0.0 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.modules.xr@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.subsystems@1.0.0 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.modules.subsystems@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.uielementsnative@1.0.0 (location: /github/workspace/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.modules.uielementsnative@1.0.0)

PlayerPrefs - Creating folder: /root/.config/unity3d/DefaultCompany
PlayerPrefs - Creating folder: /root/.config/unity3d/DefaultCompany/CiCdProject
Unable to load player prefs
[Subsystems] No new subsystems found in resolved package list.
Package Manager log level set to [2]
[Package Manager] Done registering packages in 0.05s seconds
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 0.25 ms, found 0 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.
Initialize engine version: 2020.3.15f2 (6cf78cb77498)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path /opt/unity/Editor/Data/Resources/UnitySubsystems
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path /github/workspace/Assets
GLX Extensions: GLX_ARB_context_flush_control GLX_ARB_create_context GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_ARB_get_proc_address GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_EXT_import_context GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap GLX_EXT_visual_info 
[... some more similar lines ...]
GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_r
gtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_timer_query GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_no_error GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture GL_NV_conditional_render GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_EGL_image GL_S3_s3tc
OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL 3.3 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL 3.3> ; Context handle 1921441248
Initialize mono
Mono path[0] = '/opt/unity/Editor/Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/opt/unity/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/unityjit'
Mono config path = '/opt/unity/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,server=y,suspend=n,address=127.0.0.1:56087
AcceleratorClientConnectionCallback - disconnected - :0
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Registering precompiled unity dll's ...
Register platform support module: /opt/unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/LinuxStandaloneSupport/UnityEditor.LinuxStandalone.Extensions.dll
Registered in 0.002586 seconds.
Native extension for LinuxStandalone target not found
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 0.01 ms, found 0 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.
Mono: successfully reloaded assembly
- Completed reload, in  1.910 seconds
Domain Reload Profiling:
    ReloadAssembly (1943ms)
        BeginReloadAssembly (114ms)
            ExecutionOrderSort (0ms)
            DisableScriptedObjects (0ms)
            BackupInstance (0ms)
            ReleaseScriptingObjects (0ms)
            CreateAndSetChildDomain (1ms)
        EndReloadAssembly (780ms)
            LoadAssemblies (113ms)
            RebuildTransferFunctionScriptingTraits (0ms)
            SetupTypeCache (205ms)
            ReleaseScriptCaches (0ms)
            RebuildScriptCaches (50ms)
            SetupLoadedEditorAssemblies (388ms)
                LogAssemblyErrors (0ms)
                InitializePlatformSupportModulesInManaged (15ms)
                SetLoadedEditorAssemblies (1ms)
                RefreshPlugins (0ms)
                BeforeProcessingInitializeOnLoad (27ms)
                ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes (270ms)
                ProcessInitializeOnLoadMethodAttributes (75ms)
                AfterProcessingInitializeOnLoad (0ms)
                EditorAssembliesLoaded (1ms)
            ExecutionOrderSort2 (0ms)
            AwakeInstancesAfterBackupRestoration (0ms)
Platform modules already initialized, skipping
Validating Project structure ... 0.000777 seconds.
Shader import version has changed; will reimport all shaders...
Upgrading shader files ...0.000503 seconds.
Application.AssetDatabase Initial Script Refresh Start
A meta data file (.meta) exists but its folder 'Assets/AutomatedQA/Temp' can't be found, and has been created. Empty directories cannot be stored in version control, so it's assumed that the meta data file is for an empty directory in version control. When moving or deleting folders outside of Unity, please ensure that the corresponding .meta file is moved or deleted along with it.

Start importing Assets using Guid(00000000000000001000000000000000) Importer(-1,00000000000000000000000000000000)  -> (artifact id: '022db298e6e2d271c865ba386d6c14ac') in 0.013478 seconds 
Start importing ProjectSettings/InputManager.asset using Guid(00000000000000002000000000000000) Importer(-1,00000000000000000000000000000000)  -> (artifact id: '0b0c959102eaca86ebc4dc5127dfa121') in 0.001193 seconds 
Start importing ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset using Guid(00000000000000003000000000000000) Importer(-1,00000000000000000000000000000000)  -> (artifact id: '7ecf41f796a866087ac711db5f79280f') in 0.000925 seconds 
[... some more similar lines ...]
Start importing Packages/com.unity.collab-proxy/Editor/PlasticSCM/Views/CreateWorkspace using Guid(173564ff53b74604b8e070b51861b3f9) Importer(-1,00000000000000000000000000000000)  -> (artifact id: 'c20bb1b107bc7a9c3d628fccf5f85133') in 0.000509 seconds 
Start importing Packages/com.unity.collab-proxy/Editor/Collaborate/Models/Structures using Guid(17ec05e4840248f4c8392a5f54cbadbd) Importer(-1,00000000000000000000000000000000)  -> (artifact id: '111c4ac10e32d423cc4e967294c4980a') in 0.000511 seconds 

Unloading 97 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 2060.
Total: 6.473700 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.283100 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.070000 ms MarkObjects: 3.854000 ms  DeleteObjects: 2.263600 ms)

ProgressiveSceneManager::Cancel()
Batchmode quit successfully invoked - shutting down!
[Performance] Application.InitializeProject                               :        1 samples, Peak.  5.99 s (1.0x), Avg.  5.99 s, Total. 5.995 s (84.0%)
[Performance] Application.PackageManager.StartServer                      :        1 samples, Peak.  1.70 ms (1.0x), Avg.  1.70 ms, Total. 1.698 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] Application.AcquireProjectLock                              :        1 samples, Peak.  1.91 ms (1.0x), Avg.  1.91 ms, Total. 1.907 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] Application.InitializeEngineNoGraphics                      :        1 samples, Peak.  10.7 ms (1.0x), Avg.  10.7 ms, Total. 10.66 ms (0.1%)
[Performance] Application.PackageManager.Initialize                       :        1 samples, Peak.   626 ms (1.0x), Avg.   626 ms, Total. 626.5 ms (8.8%)
[Performance] CurlRequestCheck                                            :       13 samples, Peak.  77.5 us (3.4x), Avg.  22.7 us, Total. 295.3 us (0.0%)
[Performance] VersionControl.Task.Wait                                    :        1 samples, Peak.  12.2 us (1.0x), Avg.  12.2 us, Total. 12.20 us (0.0%)
[Performance] Application.EngineGraphics.Initialize                       :        1 samples, Peak.  35.7 ms (1.0x), Avg.  35.7 ms, Total. 35.71 ms (0.5%)
[Performance] Application.GI.Initialize                                   :        1 samples, Peak.  4.48 ms (1.0x), Avg.  4.48 ms, Total. 4.480 ms (0.1%)
[Performance] Application.LoadAllDefaultResourcesFromEditor               :        1 samples, Peak.  2.63 ms (1.0x), Avg.  2.63 ms, Total. 2.630 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] Application.LoadMonoAssemblies                              :        1 samples, Peak.  1.59 s (1.0x), Avg.  1.59 s, Total. 1.587 s (22.2%)
[Performance] RestoreManagedReferences                                    :        2 samples, Peak.   136 ms (2.0x), Avg.  68.0 ms, Total. 136.0 ms (1.9%)
[Performance] ProcessService.EditorAfterLoadAllAssemblies                 :        2 samples, Peak.  50.6 ms (1.2x), Avg.  41.1 ms, Total. 82.26 ms (1.2%)
[Performance] Application.ReadLicenseInfo                                 :        1 samples, Peak.  25.7 ms (1.0x), Avg.  25.7 ms, Total. 25.70 ms (0.4%)
[Performance] Application.InitialScriptRefresh                            :        1 samples, Peak.  2.81 s (1.0x), Avg.  2.81 s, Total. 2.809 s (39.3%)
[Performance] Compiling Scripts                                           :        1 samples, Peak.   101 ms (1.0x), Avg.   101 ms, Total. 101.4 ms (1.4%)
[Performance] Application.AssetDatabase.Refresh                           :        1 samples, Peak.  91.8 ms (1.0x), Avg.  91.8 ms, Total. 91.79 ms (1.3%)
[Performance] AssetDatabase.Refresh                                       :        1 samples, Peak.  91.8 ms (1.0x), Avg.  91.8 ms, Total. 91.77 ms (1.3%)
[Performance] Application.ImportAssetsWithMismatchingAssetImporterVersion :        1 samples, Peak.   103 ms (1.0x), Avg.   103 ms, Total. 103.1 ms (1.4%)
[Performance] Application.SyncCurrentColorSpace                           :        1 samples, Peak.   158 ms (1.0x), Avg.   158 ms, Total. 157.9 ms (2.2%)
[Performance] Application.OnUsbDevicesChanged                             :        1 samples, Peak.  3.20 us (1.0x), Avg.  3.20 us, Total. 3.200 us (0.0%)
[Performance] Application.AssetInstanceCacheUpdate                        :        1 samples, Peak.   500 ns (1.0x), Avg.   500 ns, Total. 500.0 ns (0.0%)
[Performance] Application.UnityExtensions.Initialize                      :        1 samples, Peak.  2.01 ms (1.0x), Avg.  2.01 ms, Total. 2.007 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] Application.InitializeManagedCompilationPipeline            :        1 samples, Peak.  64.8 ms (1.0x), Avg.  64.8 ms, Total. 64.77 ms (0.9%)
[Performance] Application.ExecuteStartups                                 :        1 samples, Peak.  76.4 ms (1.0x), Avg.  76.4 ms, Total. 76.36 ms (1.1%)
[Performance] Gizmo.RebuildRenderers                                      :        1 samples, Peak.  69.2 ms (1.0x), Avg.  69.2 ms, Total. 69.24 ms (1.0%)
[Performance] Gizmo.AddGizmoRenderers                                     :       36 samples, Peak.  3.16 ms (21.3x), Avg.   148 us, Total. 5.334 ms (0.1%)
[Performance] Application.InitializeMenu                                  :        1 samples, Peak.  80.6 ms (1.0x), Avg.  80.6 ms, Total. 80.64 ms (1.1%)
[Performance] UpdateAllMenus                                              :        1 samples, Peak.  80.6 ms (1.0x), Avg.  80.6 ms, Total. 80.63 ms (1.1%)
[Performance] Application.editorInitializingProject                       :        1 samples, Peak.  33.0 us (1.0x), Avg.  33.0 us, Total. 33.00 us (0.0%)
[Performance] GUIView.RepaintAll.PlayerLoopController                     :        1 samples, Peak.  1.60 us (1.0x), Avg.  1.60 us, Total. 1.600 us (0.0%)
[Performance] Application.InvokeFinishedLoadingProject                    :        1 samples, Peak.  57.0 ms (1.0x), Avg.  57.0 ms, Total. 57.03 ms (0.8%)
[Performance] ProcessService.OnProjectLoaded                              :        1 samples, Peak.  52.1 ms (1.0x), Avg.  52.1 ms, Total. 52.09 ms (0.7%)
AcceleratorClientConnectionCallback - disconnected - :0
Cleanup mono
debugger-agent: Unable to listen on 44
Exiting batchmode successfully now!
Run succeeded, no failures occurred

###########################
#    COMBINE_RESULTS Results    #
###########################

chmod: cannot access '/github/workspace/CodeCoverage': No such file or directory
Changing to "/github/workspace/_activate-license" directory.
/github/workspace/_activate-license /github/workspace
/github/workspace

###########################
#         Failure         #
###########################

Please note that the exit code is not very descriptive.
Most likely it will not help you solve the issue.

To find the reason for failure: please search for errors in the log above.


Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
Error: The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 2
```

There are some Error messages that pop up like

`chmod: cannot access '/github/workspace/CodeCoverage': No such file or directory`

or

`Error: The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 2`

but it's unclear to me, whether they are really at the root of the problem or what to do about them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found a "[Simple Example](https://game.ci/docs/github/getting-started)" on the game.ci website:

```
name: Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch: {}
  pull_request: {}
  push: { branches: [master] }

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build my project ✨
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checkout
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          lfs: true

      # Cache
      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: Library
          key: Library-${{ hashFiles('Assets/**', 'Packages/**', 'ProjectSettings/**') }}
          restore-keys: |
            Library-

      # Test
      - name: Run tests
        uses: game-ci/unity-test-runner@v2
        env:
          UNITY_LICENSE: ${{ secrets.UNITY_LICENSE }}
        with:
          githubToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Build
      - name: Build project
        uses: game-ci/unity-builder@v2
        env:
          UNITY_LICENSE: ${{ secrets.UNITY_LICENSE }}
          UNITY_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.UNITY_EMAIL }}
          UNITY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.UNITY_PASSWORD }}
        with:
          targetPlatform: Android

      # Output
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Build
          path: build
```

This one, seems to run through successfully.

Minor bug:
Your `.gitignore` needs to ignore "/artifacts", [otherwise the build will fail](https://github.com/game-ci/unity-builder/issues/241).